# Navbar-brand is not showing using boostrap

Tags: html, navbar

i'm trying to fix my navbar-brand for a long time and i dont know whats wrong.. The logo is not showing when the screen is more than 750px but it shows when its under that number. This is my code till now :

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SkinLove</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar nav-tabs" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Login</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and my css:

```
.navbar{
    background-color: #FFC0CB;

}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a{
    color: #ffffff;

}
.nav.navbar-nav li a{
    color: #ffffff;

}
/*.navbar.navbar-header a .navbar-brand  {
    color: #ffffff;
}*/
.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover{
    color:#808080;
}




@media screen and (max-width: 750px){

.navbar-header {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
.navbar-brand {float:none;}

.navbar .nav-tabs{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
}
```

ps help me see what i dont see

it shows in the mobile view but not in the laptop view

Comment: Is this the full css code? something in @media screen and (max-width: 750px) media query should be hiding that logo. Also, what do you mean by logo? I don't see any logos in the example.

Comment: The logo is not a photo is the name brand(SkinLove) and yes the css code is what I’ve written till now

Answer (score 0):

This may help to resolve the issue.
Try using the `navbar-brand` directly, instead of wrapping it in a `<h1>` tag.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SkinLove</a>
```

and do the changes in CSS according to it:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a,
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

This should help to consistently display your logo despite any screen size.
if you're still getting the error, check the console and provide more information.

Comment: I used the nav at-brand directly instead of wrapping it and then changed the css but still I get the error. I checked the console too but it doesn’t show any error.. I validated my code too and all seemed ok

Comment: i updated the cdn of boostrap and it worked. It changed everything and i need to start from the beginning but atleast the logo is there. Thank you for your time!